# how i can split Array to 3 part with merge sort?

Tags: arrays, sorting

i write this algorithm usudo code to spilt my array to 3 part
Want to check the validity of this algorithm?
Are there any mistakes?

```
    function( int Basic_Array [] , int Start  , int Stop )
{
    if ( Start > Stop ) then 
    return Basic_Array 


    int NEW_Stop = ( Start + Stop ) / 3 

    int MULTI = NEW_STOP * 2 

    int Length = Basic_Array.Length 

    MergeSort ( Basic_Array  , Start , New_Stop )

    MergeSort ( Basic_Array  , New_Stop + 1 , MULTI )

    MergeSort ( Basic_Array , MULTI + 1 , Length )

}
```

Comment: so what do you want to do? you don't even show us how you do the merging.

Comment: you can do what you did.....but you jst need to change your merge function which you are not showing in your function

Comment: this algorithm only to Split the Array to 3 part .. No need to talk about merge

Comment: the array will be split but what now....you are not sorting it

Comment: I do not want to sort the array now, just want to know if you've successfully split the matrix into three parts or not ?

Comment: yes it will split into 3 arrays

Comment: come on, seriously? what do you think if the array has been splited or not?

Comment: but it will only increase computations on sorting, we split it into two to reduce these computions

Comment: This is the first stage in the work. I just want to divide the Array and then move to the Array order stage and then merge it into the whole story

Comment: I am talking about Divide and not about Sort

Comment: Did I succeed in dividing the Array into 3 parts or not? This is the only question

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr i think by "split", op wants to say if he can pass array in three diff parts to function and i am using it the same way

Comment: @monster Yes, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: @SaifMaher - consider the case: Start = 2, Stop = 4. The code sets New_Stop = 2, which is OK, but it sets MULTI = 4, which is wrong (it should be 3). The length needs to be based on Stop-Start, not Array.Length. The last call should be MergeSort(..., MULTI+1, Stop) .

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case: Start = 2, Stop = 4. The code sets New_Stop = 2, which is OK, but it sets MULTI = 4, which is wrong (it should be 3). The length needs to be based on Stop-Start, not Array.Length. The last call should be MergeSort(..., MULTI+1, Stop)

Since it's been 2 days with no activity, in case anyone is interested, example C++ code using an ending index instead of a last index. The copy loop in Merge() can be eliminated by using two mutually recursive instances of SplitMerge(), one where the sorted data ends up in a[], the other in b[], in order to alternate the direction of the merge depending on the level of recursion, but this only sped up the sort by about 8.5% for 16 million integers on my system.

Normally if doing a k way merge sort with k > 2, a bottom up merge sort is used, but in this case, the question implies that a 3 way top down merge sort is to be used.

```
void SplitMerge(int a[], int b[], int bb, int ee);
void Merge(int a[], int b[], int bb, int m1, int m2, int ee);

// bb is beginning index, ee is ending index    
void MergeSort(int a[], int bb, int ee)
{
    if((ee - bb) < 2)           // if < 2 elements
        return;
    if((ee - bb) == 2){         // if 2 elements
        ee--;                   //  ee = last index
        if(a[bb] > a[ee])       //  swap if needed
            std::swap(a[bb], a[ee]);
        return;
    }
    int *b = new int [ee-bb];  // allocate temp array
    SplitMerge(a, b, bb, ee);  // top down merge sort
    delete[] b;                // delete temp array
}

// b[] is temp array
// bb is beginning index, ee is ending index    
void SplitMerge(int a[], int b[], int bb, int ee)
{
    if((ee - bb) == 1)          // if 1 element, return
        return;
    if((ee - bb) == 2){         // if 2 elements
        ee--;                   //  ee = last index
        if(a[bb] > a[ee])       //  swap if needed
            std::swap(a[bb], a[ee]);
        return;
    }
    int sz = ((ee+1-bb)/3);     // split into 3 parts
    int m1 = bb + sz;
    int m2 = bb + sz + sz;
    SplitMerge(a, b, bb, m1);    // merge sort 1st part
    SplitMerge(a, b, m1, m2);    // merge sort 2nd part
    SplitMerge(a, b, m2, ee);    // merge sort 3rd part
    Merge(a, b, bb, m1, m2, ee); // merge the 3 parts
}

// b[] is temp array
// bb is beginning index == beg of run 0
// m1 is start of run 1  == end of run 0
// m2 is start of run 2  == end of run 1
// ee is ending index    == end of run 2
void Merge(int a[], int b[], int bb, int m1, int m2, int ee)
{
int i0 = bb;
int i1 = m1;
int i2 = m2;
int ia = bb;

    // copy a to b
    for(int i = bb; i < ee; i++)
        b[i] = a[i];

    while(1){                           // merge run 0, 1, 2
        if(b[i0] <= b[i1] && b[i0] <= b[i2]){  // if run0[] smallest
            a[ia++] = b[i0++];
            if(i0 < m1)                 // if not end of run 0
                continue;               //   continue back to while
            i0 = i1;                    // merge runs 1 and 2
            i1 = i2;
            m1 = m2;
            m2 = ee;
            break;
        }
        if(b[i1] <= b[i2]){             // if run1[] smallest
            a[ia++] = b[i1++];
            if(i1 < m2)                 // if not end of run 1
                continue;               //   continue back to while
            i1 = i2;                    // merge runs 0 and 2
            m2 = ee;
            break;
        } else {                        // else run2[] smallest
            a[ia++] = b[i2++];
            if(i2 < ee)                 // if not end of run 2
                continue;               //   continue back to while
            break;                      // merge runs 0 and 1
        }
    }

    while(1){                           // merge runs "0" and "1"
        if(b[i0] <= b[i1]){             // if run0[] smallest
            a[ia++] = b[i0++];
            if(i0 < m1)                 // if not end of run 0
                continue;               //   continue back to while
            i0 = i1;                    // copy rest of run 1
            m1 = m2;
            break;
        } else {                        // else run1[] smallest
            a[ia++] = b[i1++];
            if(i1 < m2)                 // if not end of run 1
                continue;               //   continue back to while
            break;                      // copy rest of run 0
        }
    }

    do                                  // copy rest of run "0"
        a[ia++] = b[i0++];
    while(i0 < m1);
}
```